# Djano: how to update order tracker model using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to build an order tracker using django, to track the delivery status and location of a order made by a buyer.
i have a model that look like this

```
class OrderTracker(models.Model):
    order_item = models.ForeignKey('store.CartOrderItem', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="cartorderitem_tracker")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank=True)
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank=True)
    date= models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.order_item
```

When an order gets placed, the status of the `OrderTracker` changes to shipping.
How do i update the location with the current location where the order is crrently and also the activity *(activity is something like: "Left Warehouse")*

Should this is updated manully by the vendor in the dashboard, or do i need like an API to implement this feature